# Suppress output for windows move command

Tags: windows, command-prompt, windows-console

Here is simple move command that moves all the text files to the folder TextFiles

```
Move *.txt TextFiles
```

I am getting outputs like the file was moved.
I am going to use this command in a `batch` file. Any way to suppress showing the user that a file was moved ?

Answer (score 18):

```
Move *.txt TextFiles >nul
```

`>nul` sends the standard output to oblivion. `2>nul` sends error messages to the same place.